# Можно ли сделать словарь только для чтения?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, класс внутри себя содержит дженерик словарь.
Я бы хотел его прокинуть наружу, но с запретом на редактирование.
Как это можно сделать?

Есть мысль индексаторы наружу выставить, но может быть, как-то по-другому можно?

Например, для списков есть `ReadOnlyCollection`

Comment: [IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2.keys?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyClass 
{
  private Dictionary<string, string> fItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Items => fItems;
  ...
}
```